# TypeError: Can't instantiate abstract class OrderGenaratorForTransfomer with abstract methods __len__

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow

I am trying to write my own data generator for a TensorFlow model and at this stage, I am only testing

```
import numpy as np

class OrderGenaratorForTransfomer(Sequence):
    n_products = 1000
    n_windows = 10
    n_customers = 10
    def __init__(
        self
    ):
        pass

    def __getitem__(self, item):
        X = np.zeros((self.n_customers, self.n_windows, self.n_products))
        Y = np.zeros((self.n_customers, 1, self.n_products))

        return X, Y
```

I did not define a `__len__` method and I am getting the error
`TypeError: Can't instantiate abstract class OrderGenaratorForTransfomer with abstract methods __len__`

My question is a more conceptual one, why does the generator need to have a defined `__len__` method for the generator to work properly? I can think of some ideas but wanted to find out from someone who might know more definitevly.

Comment: Because `Sequence.__len__` is abstract, so it must be defined by any subclass. There is not really much more to it

Comment: Oh, I see, I wasn't familiar with what abstract meant so it seemed like a more involved situation.